# Algorithm and R code for dealing with ties in Wilcoxon rank-sum test

Tags: r, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, ranks

1. I think one of the  algorithms used to handle ties for the Wilcoxon rank-sum test (a.k.a., Mann-Whitney U test) is Streitberg / Rohmel. I could not find a good source which explains the algorithm / gives a proof / or even simply outlines the algorithm. Could someone please explain this algorithm, or some other algorithm which also solves the ties problem?
2. What would be the R code used to get exact p-values / distributions for a Wilcoxon rank-sum test (a.k.a., Mann-Whitney U test)?

Answer (score 7):

1. The Streitberg-Röhmel shift algorithm is described in two manuscripts:

   - Streitberg B, Röhmel J (1986). "Exact Distributions for Permutation and Rank Tests: An Introduction to Some Recently Published Algorithms." *Statistical Software Newsletter*, **12**(1), 10-17. ISSN 1609-3631.
   - Streitberg B, Röhmel J (1987). "Exakte Verteilungen für Rang- und Randomisierungstests im allgemeinen c-Stichprobenfall." *EDV in Medizin und Biologie*, **18**(1), 12-19.

   Both are not exactly mainstream journals and one manuscript is in German...which explains why this algorithm is less well-known than the network algorithm by Mehta & Patel underlying their proprietary StatXact software.

   The Streitberg-Röhmel shift algorithm (and Van de Wiel's split-up algorithm) are implemented in the R package `coin` for conditional inference. See:

   - Hothorn T, Hornik K, Van de Wiel MA, Zeileis A (2006). "A Lego System for Conditional Inference". *The American Statistician*, **60**(3), 257-263.
   - Hothorn T, Hornik K, Van de Wiel MA, Zeileis A (2008). "Implementing a Class of Permutation Tests: The coin Package." [*Journal of Statistical Software*, **28**(8), 1-23](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v28/i08/).
2. The R code for the Streitberg-Röhmel algorithm is contained in the file `coin/R/ExactDistributions.R` in the `coin` source package, available from [CRAN](http://CRAN.R-project.org/package=coin).

Answer (score 0):

Actually, on [this website](https://ccb-compute2.cs.uni-saarland.de/wtest/) you can find an implemented version of the Wilcoxon Rank-Sum test which provides the **exact solution for data that involves ties** and also for data without ties. In addition, quite **big sample sizes** can be solved (at the moment $A, B \le 200$).

(The reference is Marx, A.; Backes, C.; Meese, E.; Lenhof, H. P.; and Keller, A.; *EDISON-WMW: Exact Dynamic Programming Solution of the Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney Test.*  Genomics Proteomics Bioinformatics, 14(1): 55--61. Feb 2016.)

The algorithm behind the code uses dynamic programming to do a complete search and enumerate efficiently all subproblems to be able to calculate the exact p-value without any approximations or corrections.

Comment: Now that the Web site is dead, there's no information in this answer that addresses the question.  Could you supply the missing information?

Comment: Updated the link.

Comment: +1 Thank you, Alex: it looks like a truly useful resource.