# Wilcox test with Jitter because of ties - valid?

Tags: r, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

I have data where there are two groups, there is only a single observation for one of the groups, but lots of observations for the second group.  There are quite a few zero and one values for the second group (the measurement is a ratio out of 1).  Doing a normal wilcox gives the error regarding too many ties however this is fixed if I do wilcox.test(jitter(a) ~ b).  Is this a valid way to go about things?

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/147000/17230. The point of testing's to find whether a signal's discernible through the noise; adding noise isn't going to help.

Comment: Do you mean the warning message that says "cannot compute exact p-value with ties"?  That wouldn't imply that there are *too many* ties...

Comment: "There is only a single observation for one of the groups." ?  That sounds like an unenviable situation.