# Exact p-value calculation for Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney U-Test in the presence of ties

Tags: wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

Mann and Whitney's paper on the Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney U-Test (https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aoms/1177730491) shows how to calculate the p-value when the samples are small: an exact recursive calculation is feasible.

However, this case, as treated in the paper, seems limited to the situation when there are no ties in the data. Can a p-value be calculated exactly for small sample sizes when there *are* ties? Said differently, is there an adaptation of the small-samples case for a fractional U?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/152576/805